# What to call $x^{-1}ax$?

Tags: group-theory, terminology

If $G$ is a group and $a,x\in G$, then would we call $x^{-1}ax$ a conjugate of $x$ or a conjugate of $a$?

Sorry for such a short question, was just doing a problem and want to call this something so it is easier for me to refer to and I want to call it what seems to be the normal way to say it.

Comment: Thank you guys so much for your answers!

Comment: I'd call it the conjugate of $a$ by $x^{-1}$.  I'd reserve the term conjugate of $a$ by $x$ for $x a x^{-1}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We call $x^{-1}ax$ a conjugate of $a$.

You can say that you conjugated $a$ by $x$.

You should note, in general, $a$ is NOT conjugate to $x$, for arbitrary elements of $G$.

Answer (score 2):

$x^{-1}ax$ is the conjugate of $a$ by $x$. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Conjugation.html